# Intrusion is possible through firmware signature file

Tags: security, nas, firmware, freenas

I have a small NAS system and recently i got a firmware to upload the features.

I have one image file and a signature file.

I just trying to edit the signature file and append some junk character at end of the line.

When am trying to upgrade it upgrade the firmware with out any issue.

So i contacted the dev team of NAS box and explain the scenario.

As per they said they are calculating sign file length so what ever come at the end they ignore.

They asked me below scenario. But below scenario is working fine.

1.) Delete one or more characters from in between/beginning/end of the file and then add the same number of different characters other than deleted. This will retain size but the characters will be changed.

2.) Delete some content thereby reducing the size.

3.) Add more characters in "between/beginning" thereby increasing the size.

So my question is appending something at end sign  file can not be a problem?
any malicious code can be injected through sign file?

Thanks in advance. Not sure this type question is accepted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, firmware should only be uploaded by people trusted with the entire system. Allowing someone to upload firmware is basically the same as allowing them to do whatever with the system, as the firmware can potentially be altered to benefit [Robbie Rotten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbie_Rotten).

As for your case, I cannot say for sure because I do not know the specifics of your hardware, but I do know of many devices that require firmware images to be of a specific size to allow an upload. To make it fit, extra data is padded, but ignored like you say. If this extra data was actually kept, it would in theory be possible to have this data be code that could later be called with some low-level programming, but I do not consider this a real threat, as an attacker would already need substantial access levels for this to be allowed - To access functions buried in data padded to the firmware, he would already be required to run arbitrary code.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but through firmware It certainly is possible, so only download firmware (and drivers and upgrades for apps that came with your device) from a trustworthy site. That does not mean your PC (or external device) is infected, though. It also depends how the firmware is installed -- if you must execute an application on your PC to install the update, it would be easier to engineer malware into it. If firmware is installed by the external device (e.g. by copying files to a memory card and then inserting it into a camera), it is unlikely that malware was installed on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's the scenario #1 that can be exploited. If you can replace some characters in the firmware and/or in the signature file, and those files are not rejected during a firmware upgrade, then the signature check isn't actually performed and you can be tricked to upload malicious code on your NAS box disguised as firmware upgrade.